# Object Permissions - App SDK vs WEB API

Tags: rally

I wrote a reporting app that aggregates lots of information for an iteration. One of the things it does is query individual defects to display their details in certain places. It works perfectly but there is a group of users at another office where the defect information comes up blank.

I see that the queries for these defects are returning 0 results. This confuses me because if I run the same query for a defect in the Web API as that same user that is running the app, the defect is returned. The user can also see the defect in Rally.

Is there any differences in the permissions required by the App SDK and Web API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Web Services API enforces the same permissions as the normal Rally Web App.

My guess is you are seeing one of two issues:

1. The users of your App cannot see the defects because they are in a project that they have no permissions on. You can test this by sending them a link to one of the defects that you would expect them to be able to see.
2. The users have a different project selected or their project scoping is different than what is on your machine. This is likely the culprit if they can see the link you sent them in step one. In this case you can also set the scope of the App to the project that you are interested in reporting from.

This image below shows the interface for locking an App to a specific scope.

You just need to "Choose Specific Project" and find the project you are interested in reporting from. Note this

[image]

I made a mini App that just displays what the project id that the App is currently showing which is located at this [gist](http://goo.gl/SvMLR).

Comment: They do have permission for the project. I confirmed that again. For project scoping, where are those settings? I've looked but all I can see is the checkboxes on the project dropdown in Rally. I know where/how it works in my app code, but for the user settings I'm not sure where this is. Thanks.

Comment: Hrmm. I tried setting project scoping to true for the RallyDataSource but that didn't fix the issue. By setting it true there, that should override user settings, right? Or would I still need to find where the user setting it?

Comment: If you want to set it to a specific scope you need to put a reference to the project in the constructor. http://developer.rallydev.com/rally-data-source If you want to create a new question with some code in it I can help you there. I think this question is pretty valuable without the specifics of what SDK you are using.

Comment: Hrmm. In what I'm trying to do, it's not really known which project the defect will be in. I'm guessing that it works for myself and everyone here because we have at minimum viewer permissions in all related projects. I might just have to figure out a new way of doing what we want to do with the app. Thanks for the info, I'll pose a question about scoping after I do a little more research and thinking about the problem.